# Substring function not working when truncated using mysql

Tags: mysql, substring

Want to remove the last character in mysql as follows:

```
select substring(item, 1, length(item) - 1)
from table
```

But mysql returns the complete string containing the last char, the type of 'item' is mediumtext. The `left` function seems to have the same problem.

Comment: Not reproduced. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c6844be81dfd47c25e20ec6568219737). I think that there exists some non-printable char(s) at the end of the value (newline, for example).

Comment: You could at least check if `length(item)` returns what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for you answers. The reason is that some characters are more than one byte. Use char_length solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that some characters are more than one byte. Use char_length solves the problem.